# ¿Cómo obtener mes del año anterior con SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

¿Cómo puedo obtener mes del año anterior con `SQL Server`? Con lo que es el `GETDATE()` o parecido.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hola Acd, me parece que la pregunta es buena, sin embargo, para que quede del todo claro, sería bueno nos dieras más detalle, también que agregaras un ejemplo de lo que deseas obtener, y en la medida de lo posible, código con el que has intentado, esto para no caer en especulaciones y poder darte una respuesta más puntual :)

Comment: No está clara la pregunta y es evidente por las respuestas que contestan otra cosa. **mes del año anterior**... por ejemplo, ¿ *marzo 2016* es _"mes del año anterior"_, tomando como base la fecha actual (3 de marzo de 2017)?

Comment: quieres el nombre o quieres el numero del mes
`select MONTH(dateadd(year, -1,getdate()))` -- con esto se ve el numero
`select DATENAME(month,dateadd(year, -1,getdate()))` -- con esto se ve el nombre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar la función DATEADD,

```
SELECT DATEADD(year, -1,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Con eso obtienes el año anterior, sin embargo me parece que en la pregunta dice ***obtener mes del año anterior*** :)

Comment: @Flxtr es la mitad de la respuesta, no le cuesta nada averiguar la otra mitad :) si no es que ya la sabe. El chiste es encaminar no hacer todo por ellos.

Comment: Coincido totalmente contigo :D por eso le escribí un comentario para que nos aclare realmente qué requiere y de igual forma nos diga qué es lo que ha intentado.

Comment: Sin embargo si es así, esta "respuesta" cave en un comentario. Tienes la actitud, Migue, la rep va llegar.

Comment: Si la respuesta fué aceptada, ¿Será pertinente editar la pregunta para que esta sea la respuesta correcta? Si otro usuario busca esta respuesta, no va a dar con ella por que la pregunta es confusa.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [YEAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx):

```
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) AS [Año]
```

Comment: De hecho, tendría que ser `GETDATE()` (con paréntesis) y por lo que entiendo el OP requiere el mes del año anterior, con eso solo se obtendría el año actual

Comment: @Flxtr tienes razón, corregido.